# Named Graphs and Federated SPARQL Endpoints

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, named-graphs, federated-queries

I recently came across the working draft for [SPARQL 1.1 Federation Extensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-sparql11-federated-query-20100601/) and wondered whether this was already possible using Named Graphs (not to detract from the usefulness of the aforementioned draft).

My understanding of Named Graphs is a little hazy, save that the only thing I have gleamed from reading the specs comprises rules around the merger, non merger in relation to other graphs at query time. Since this doesn't fully satisfy my understanding, my question is as follows:

Given the following query:

```
SELECT ?something
FROM NAMED <http://www.vw.co.uk/models/used>
FROM NAMED <http://www.autotrader.co.uk/cars/used>
WHERE {
    ...
}
```

Is it reasonable to assume that a query processor/endpoint could or should in the context of the named graphs do the following:

1. Check is the named graph exists locally
2. If it doesn't then perform the following operation (in the case of the above query, I will use the second named graph)

   GET /sparql/?query=EncodedQuery HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.autotrader.co.uk
    User-agent: my-sparql-client/0.1

Where the EncodedQuery only includes the second named graph in the `FROM NAMED` clause and the `WHERE` clause is amended accordingly with respect to `GRAPH` clauses (e.g if a `GRAPH <http://www.vw.co.uk/models/used> {...}` is being used).

**Only if it can't perform the above**, then do any of the following:

```
GET /cars/used HTTP/1.1
Host: www.autotrader.co.uk
```

or

```
LOAD <http://www.autotrader.co.uk/cars/used>
```

3. Return appropriate search results.

Obviously there might be some additional considerations around `OFFSET`'s and `LIMIT`'s

I also remember reading somewhere a long time ago in galaxy far far away, that the default graph of any SPARQL endpoint should be a named graph according to the following convention:

For: http://www.vw.co.uk/sparql/ there should be a named graph of: http://www.vw.co.uk that represents the default graph and so by the above logic, it should already be possible to federate SPARQL endpoints using named graphs.

The reason I ask is that I want to start promoting federation across the domains in the above example, without having to wait around for the standard, making sure that I won't do something that is out of kilter or incompatible with something else in the future.

Comment: Named graphs and federated queries are rather orthogonal functionalities. Think of named graphs as particular subsets of (local) triples. For queries to remote endpoints, the `SERVICE` keyword is used. AFAIK, Jena Assembler allows to map named graphs to local files, and probably other triplestores allow to map named graphs to remote triplesets, but these solutions are vendor specific. As for default names for default graphs, [this specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-service-description/) currently doesn't contain something of this kind.

Comment: It seems that the feature you are talking about is Virtuoso-specific, see e. g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409110/sparql-federated-query-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Named graph and URLs used in federated queries (using SERVICE or FROM) are two different things. The latter point to SPARQL endpoints, the named graphs are within a triple store and have the main function of separating different data sets. This, in turn, can be useful to both improve performance and represent knowledge, such as representing what is the source of a set of statements.

For instance, you might have two data sources both stating that `?movie has-rating ?x` and you might want to know which source is stating which rating, in this case you can use two named graphs associated to the two sources (e.g., `http://www.example.com/rotten-tomatoes` and `http://www.example.com/imdb`). If you're storing both data sets in the same triple store, probably you will want to use NGs, and remote endpoints are a different thing. Furthermore, the URL of a named graph can be used with vocabularies like [VoID](https://www.w3.org/TR/void/) to describe a dataset as a whole (eg, the data set name, where and when the triples are imported from, who is the maintainer, user licence). This is another reason to partition your triple store into NGs.

That said, your mechanism to bind NGs to endpoint URLs might be implemented as an option, but I don't think it's a good idea to have it as mandatory, since managing remote endpoint URLs and NGs separately can be more useful.

Moreover, the real challenge in federated queries is to offer endpoint-transparent queries, making the query engine smart enough to analyse the query and understand how to split it and perform partial queries on the right endpoints (and join the results later, in an efficient way). There is a lot of research being done on that, one of the most significant results (as far as I know) is [FedX](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-25073-6_38), which has been used to implement several query distribution optimisations ([example](https://jbiomedsem.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13326-017-0112-6)).

Last thing to add, I vaguely remember the convention that you mention about $url, $url/sparql. There are a couple of approaches around (e.g., [LOD cloud](http://lod-cloud.net)). That said, in most nowadays triple stores (e.g., Virtuoso), queries that don't specify a named graph (don't use GRAPH) work in a way different than falling into a default graph case, they actually query the union of all named graphs in the store, which is usually much more useful (when you don't know where something is stated, or you want to integrate cross-graph data).